# SplashScreen with download website and pass it to webview

Tags: android, webview, android-asynctask

I would like to open app with splashscreen activity and download homepage of my website. When download complete I'd like to start MainActivity, pass webssite to webview and display it.
I tried some different methods but nothing works.. 
My current version load webview when MainActivity starts and that not looks good when website is loading. 
Do you have any ideas?

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen_layout);
        try {
            url = new URL(link);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        new WczytywaczUrl().execute(url);
    }
    //asynctask class and methods
    @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.d(TAG, result.toString());
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("strona", result);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }


    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "metoda onCreate");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        String strona = i.getStringExtra("strona");
        Log.d(TAG, "strona: " + strona.toString());
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(link, strona, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
    }
    }
```

Comment: The posted code should work. In the splash screen activity the web page is downloaded. Then after that the main activity is started and the page is transferred by intent and loaded in a webview. What does not work exactly?

Comment: it looks like splashScreen doesnt download all html file to string, so it dont pass all data to mainactivity and webview is downloading from internet(not from string)

Comment: Your comment is confusing. In your code the webview is presented the downloaded web page in `String strona`. If the asynctask does not fully download the page then you should have stated that right away. What is not complete of the source html?

Comment: when i print it strona in logcat it end at '<link re'.

Comment: also when MainActivity runs i have to wait few seconds to see completely downloaded webview

Comment: How can it show 'completely downloaded' if the source is not complete? Again confusing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about replacing "Activity" with just another layout?

```
<FrameLayout>
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Layout1
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
           // Layout contents that origin from your splash activity layout
    </Layout1>
    <Layout2
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible">
           // Layout contents that origin from your main activity layout
    </Layout2>
</FrameLayout>
```

WebViewClient has "[public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html)" callback.

If you implement code that change visibility of Layout1 and Layout2 in that callback,
then the webview may be shown after it finished loading.